# How can I tell whether an iOS game/app saves its data to iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud

I'd like to delete a game off of an iOS device but I would prefer to not lose my progress in case I want to return. Is there any way of checking whether the game/app puts the game save either in iCloud or another external service?

Comment: Usually each game asks you to log in with Game Center in order to save the game data onto your account and get it back whenever you log in to it independentlyfrom the iDevice using. What game do you want to delete though?

Answer (score 1):

You can see a list of apps using iCloud storage from the Settings → iCloud → Storage → Manage Storage menu. But even if your app is listed, there's no way of checking exactly what data is saved.

Answer (score 0):

If you back up the iDevice via iCloud, the game data will be saved there. You can also use iExplorer on a Mac or Windows machine.

This tutorial will show you how: http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/132888-how-to-transfer-app-and-game-data-between-ios-devices