# Let a friend/child try a game on iOS?

Tags: ios, icloud, apple-id, data, game-center

Is there currently (iOS 12) any way to let a friend or child try a game on an iOS device, starting from the tutorial, without losing my own progress?

Answer (score 3):

In general, no. The game developer can store progress on the device locally, [on an iCloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245519/how-can-i-tell-whether-an-ios-game-app-saves-its-data-to-icloud) / [Game Center log in basis](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25371/how-do-i-delete-data-for-one-game-in-the-ipad-game-center) (or both) or save data off on a [private server / public cloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126884/how-to-transfer-clash-of-clans-from-one-ios-device-to-another).

It really depends very specifically on how the [game was programmed to behave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124012/two-clash-of-clan-accounts-under-one-game-center-account) and you’d need to contact each vendor / read their documentation or experiment to understand how or if game progress and data persist on iOS.

Even deleting an app won't remove some game data and some people love that and others, not so much.

- [Can I delete an iOS game and retain my progress?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45917/can-i-delete-an-ios-game-and-retain-my-progress)

Answer (score 0):

Settings → Game Centre has options to Sign out, set up different Apple ID for Game Centre or use a different profile.

Comment: That would rather depend on whether or not the game depends on the Game Centre. if the progress is saved externally, at the game dev's own site, the it may not be possible.

Comment: @Tetsujin But that remotely stored progress would be exclusive to ID. Mapping it to the device is troubling .

Comment: @ankiiiiiii There is all manner of troubling behavior that ships. Some games even store parts of data in Game Center, part in iCloud, part on the device so it’s really a mixed bag of every flavor beans - https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Bertie_Bott%27s_Every_Flavour_Beans

Comment: @ankiiiiiii I suppose this doesn't allow easily switching between multiple IDs?